# $g(x) = f(x)(1+f(x)^4)$. If $g\in C^k, k\ge 1$, prove that $f$ is also of class $C^k$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

> Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that, for all
>   $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $g(x) = f(x)(1+f(x)^4)$. If $g\in C^k, k\ge 1$,
>   prove that $f$ is also of class $C^k$

My book does the following:

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\phi(x,y) = g(x)-y(1+y^4)$. Then $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}(x,y) = -1-5y^4\neq 0$. **This way, for all $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, by doing $y_0=f(x_0)$, we have $\phi(x_0,y_0) = 0$.** By the implicit function theorem, there exists a ball $B(x_0,\delta)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, an interval $J = [y_0-\epsilon, y_0+\epsilon]$ and a function $\eta:B\to J$ where $\eta\in C^k$ such that, for all $x\in B, \eta(x)$ is the only point in $J$ such that $\phi(x,\eta(x)) = 0$. Since $f$ is continuous, we can take $\delta>0$ so small that $f(B)\subset J$. Knowing that $\phi(x,f(x)) = 0$ for all $x\in B$, we conclude that $f(x) = \eta(x)$ if $x\in B$, so $f\in C^k$

In the bold phrase: if the goal is to show that there exists such function $\eta(x)$ such that $\phi(x,\eta(x)) = 0$, why does $\phi(x_0,y_0) = 0$ for all $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$? Why is this useful anyways?

Comment: 27 questions asked so far, but only 2 answers accepted. Hmmm... the kind of user that I avoid.

Comment: @AlexM. Hi, I always accept the answers after 3 or 5 days

Comment: Really? Then take a look at [your own activity](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/385763/paprika?tab=questions) and decide for yourself if you really do as you claim.

Comment: Is your question about the implicit function theorem? The point of the theorem is having any $\phi(x,\eta(x))$ equal to some constant, zero in particular, as you want $g(x)=f(x)(1+f(x)^4)$